# Laravel- Auto fill input after selecting value from dropdown

Tags: mysql, ajax, laravel, select

how to do the auto fill after select the dropdown list. I'm not really good in js or ajax.
When user select doc_no then both rev_no and title field must be filled up. Thanks!

View

```php
 <div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('text', 'Doc No', ['class' => 'col-lg-3 control-label']) !!}
<div class="col-lg-10">
<select name="docNo" id="docNo" class="form-control" style="width:250px">

@foreach ($soplists as $soplist)
<option value="{{ $soplist->id }}">{{ $soplist->doc_no }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div>
</div>



<input type="hidden" name="carType" value="Internal Audit" class="form-control">

<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('text', "Rev No", ['class' => 'col-lg-5 control-label']) !!}
<div class="col-lg-5">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="rev" />

</div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('text', "Title", ['class' => 'col-lg-5 control-label']) !!}
<div class="col-lg-10">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" />

</div>
```

```
<script>
    $('#docNo').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var url = '{{ route("getDetails", ":id") }}';
        url = url.replace(':id', id);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    $('#rev').val(response.rev_no);
                    $('#title').val(response.title);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller
---php

```
   public function getDetails($id = 0)
{
    $data = sopList::where('doc_no', $id)->first();
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

---

Route

```
'Route::get('get/details/{id}', 'internalAuditController@getDetails')->name('getDetails');'
```

Database sop_list table image link

https://ibb.co/SwkJhLc

Dropdown and input image

https://ibb.co/0VN3Z2y

Network tab

https://ibb.co/56w5BLD

Comment: What you have tried. Show some code.

Comment: @BhavikKalariya hello i have just updated my question!

Comment: with what value the input fields will be filled up??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon after select doc_no then the input must filled up with rev_no and title

Comment: well i mean from where the values will come??database??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes from mysql (sop_list) table

Comment: Edited my answer with mysql table image

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a route in `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('get/details/{id}', 'YourController@getDetails')->name('getDetails');
```

Controller Function:

```
public function getDetails($id = 0)
{
    $data = sopList::where('doc_no',$id)->first();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

And in view the script:

```
$('#docNo').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = '{{ route("getDetails", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', id);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            if(response != null){
                $('#rev').val(response.rev_no);
                $('#title').val(response.title);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

> Make sure to add the id `rev` and `title` to the `rev` and `title` input fields respectively.

Comment: Thanks bro but it's still doesnt work. I've update my question with your codes. Can u check if there's any mistake.

Comment: seems ok to me. can you inspect whether your ajax request is working or not from the network tab of your browser console??

Comment: click on a single one and check what response controller returns.

Comment: I'm not really understand with this thing. I there any other way to fix this.

Comment: you have to learn things to solve your problem. try to learn how to use browser console to handle ajax requests. :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to make a rout that returns what you need
for example

```
 /**
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function getCategories()
{
    $category = Category::where('_id', request()->get('_id'))
        ->select(['name', '_id'])->first();

    return response()->json($category);
}
```

then call it on change of your select box with ajax and show it every where you want
like this example:

```
$("#docNo").change(function () {    
 $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('getCategories') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                _id: $(this).val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                 var newOption = '';
                    $.each(data, function (k, category) {
                        newOption += '<option value="' + category.id +                         '">' + category.name + '</option>';
                    });

                    $('#parent').append(newOption);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
        });
```

Comment: Hey how about the select in view? do i need to replace anything? thanks

Comment: my code is just a sample you have to change it to what you want but the base is the same. you need a rout and ajax call on change of your select

Answer (score 1):

you can add onChange method on your docNo and then call do ajax call to get the rev_no and title and update the content via document.getElementById()